# Python Selenium - Get url from a listbox instead of clicking it

Tags: python, selenium

I want to send search term to a listbox, capture/print the url instead of clicking on it. If there is a better way than using Selenium that would also be acceptable also. 
Example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

#Choose Browser
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(1)
#Go to url
driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/")
#fill out search field
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/nav/nav/form/div/div/div/input""").send_keys("eth")
#Select first option from dropdown
listbox = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/nav/nav/form/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span"))
print(listbox.select_by_index(0)) # I want to print the link instead of clicking it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that simply entering text in the searchbox did not show the dropdown. Here is a sample of code that will give you the innerHTML of the dropdown. You can modify the xpath to get your specific `li` element or parse it accordingly with BeautifulSoup.

```
driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/")
#fill out search field
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/nav/nav/form/div/div/div/input""")
search_box.click()
time.sleep(1)
search_box.send_keys("eth")
#Select first option from dropdown
listbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='cmc-popover__dropdown']")
print(listbox.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Edit: Also, if the driver instance is not wide enough, the search box won't appear. Consider opening it maximized.